# PHP factory for returning conditional objects after verification?

Tags: php, class, factory

I basically need to call one of two constructors from my PHP class dependent on wheter or not verification is needed.

My current code looks like this:

```
class Event extends Generic {

    private $user_id;

    function __construct($user_id=null) {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }

    public function verify($user_id=null, $identifier=null) {

        if (parent::verifyUser($user_id, $identifier)) {
            return new Event($user_id);
        }
        else {
            // what gets retruend here in the event of a failure???
        }
    }

    public function noverify($user_id=null) {
        return new Event(user_id);
    }
}
```

Calling the code like so:

```
$event = new Event();
$obj1 = $event->noverify(5);
$obj2 = $event->verify(5, 100);
```

I'm really not clear how I should handle the event of a failed constructor if the condition inside fails.  Am I heading down the wrong path here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either throw an Exception or return `FALSE`:

```
else {
    throw new Exception('verification failed');
}
```

or

```
else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Why false instead of null ?

Comment: normally PHP agreed that if a function fails `false` should be returned. Nowadays almost every core function is doing so.

Comment: I assume this is from the time when PHP was closer to C than it currently is. Since an object is supposed to be returned, it seems more natural to me not to return anything in case of failure than returning a boolean. Besides some functions could return false on success. For example isFeatureEnabled($feature). If a valid parameter is given, the function succeeds but is still likely to return false.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. Firstly, PHP was never close to C (C hasn't even a boolean type), secondly, in former versions of PHP some functions returned `NULL`, `-1`, ... some `FALSE` on error.. In a process of unifying the php core it was decided that `FALSE` should being used - if `FALSE` is not a valid return on success. And as PHP is not close to `C` (it is far from), having different datatypes of return values is fully OK. At last there are also methods which will return `NULL` on success, like  `User::findSingle(1)` which will return a user if the id is valid or `NULL` if not